# How to setup LocalDateTime in Spring XML configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring

My problem relates to the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
}
```

I am trying to setup the startDate property of this bean using Spring XML configuration:

```
<property name="startDate">
   <value>2000-01-01</value>
</property>
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.LocalDateTime] for property 'startDate'
```

Is it possible to use Spring to do this conversion? I found examples on the [net](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/beans-spring/spring-inject-date-into-bean-property-with-customdateeditor/) how to do that for Date object, however, LocalDateTime doesn't have a constructor taking a string (and the solution seems to need such constructor). LocalDateTime is constructed by using the static method LocalDateTime.parse.

Using the annotations @DateTimeFormat, like:

```
public class MyClass {
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
}
```

is not a solution, since MyClass has to be available outside Spring.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you can register your conversion. like the following code, the following will convert a string to `LocalDateTime`

```
class CustomLocalDateTimeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

private final boolean allowEmpty;
private final int exactDateLength;

public CustomLocalDateTimeEditor( boolean allowEmpty) {
    this.allowEmpty = allowEmpty;
    this.exactDateLength = -1;
}

public CustomLocalDateTimeEditor(boolean allowEmpty, int exactDateLength) {
    this.allowEmpty = allowEmpty;
    this.exactDateLength = exactDateLength;
}

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (this.allowEmpty && !StringUtils.hasText(text)) {
        setValue(null);
    }
    else if (text != null && this.exactDateLength >= 0 && text.length() != this.exactDateLength) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse date: it is not exactly" + this.exactDateLength + "characters long");
    }
    else {
        try {
            setValue(LocalDateTime.parse(text));
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse date: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    LocalDateTime value = LocalDateTime.parse(String.valueOf(getValue()));
    return (value != null ? value.toString() : "");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with based on Javy's comment:

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class CustomLocalDateTimeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

   public CustomLocalDateTimeEditor() {
   }

   private LocalDateTime parseText(String text) {
      LocalDateTime ldt;
      try {
         ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(text);
      } catch(Exception ee) {
         ldt = null;
      }

      if(ldt == null) {
         try {
            ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(text), LocalTime.of(0, 0));
         } catch(Exception ee) {
            ldt = null;
         }
      }

      return ldt;
   }

   @Override
   public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      setValue(parseText(text));
   }

   @Override
   public String getAsText() {
      LocalDateTime value = parseText(String.valueOf(getValue()));
      return (value != null ? value.toString() : "");
   }

}
```

And in the XML I have the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
   <property name="customEditors">
      <map>
         <entry key="java.time.LocalDateTime" value="com.mycompany.CustomLocalDateTimeEditor" />
      </map>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myClass" class="MyClass">
   <property name="startDate">
      <value>2000-01-01</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use @DateTimeFormat annotation and provide a pattern. For example

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDateTime startDate;
```

When Spring find the Joda localdatetime, it will convert date in appropriate format.

[@DateTimeFormat in spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html)

Comment: As I stated in the question - I cannot use this solution.

Comment: You are setting your startDate property of MyClass in spring configuration file, then how would it be possible that you are using outside the spring? If  you are declaring your bean in the spring configuration file, then spring will read the bean and throws any error otherwise spring will never read your bean.

Comment: The library containing MyClass doesn't use Spring, but follows bean conventions. The application which uses this library uses Spring too and can configure objects it uses.

Answer (score -1):

Declare a `dateFormat` bean, in “`MyClass`” bean, reference “`dateFormat`” bean as a factory bean. The factory method will call `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` to convert String into Date object automatically.

reference:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-pass-a-date-into-bean-property-customdateeditor/